# Azure Stream Analytics Query to consolidate two events

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I try to consolidate two **different** events (EventB and EventC) that come from the same EventHub input. What I want to achieve is to output (Azure Function) a consolidated event (EventB + EventC) **whenever** a EventC is received.

This is how the events looks like:

```
{
    "EventB": {
        "Claim": {
            "EventAUri": "A/123",
            "Uri": "B/456"
        },
        "Metainfo": {
            "Color": "Green"
        }
    }   
}
```

and

```
{
    "EventC" : {
        "Claim": {
            "EventBUri": "B/456"
        },
        "Target": {
            "City": "Berlin",
            "Position": {
                "Latitude": 50.325096,
                "Longitude": 72.19710
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EventB will be sent only one time whereas EventC will be sent a few times per minute. The desired output for the above example would be:

```
    {
        "Claim": {
            "EventBUri": "B/456"
        },
        "Target": {
            "City": "Berlin",
            "Position": {
                "Latitude": 50.325096,
                "Longitude": 72.19710
            }
        },
        "BMetainfo": {
            "Color": "Green"
        }
    }
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
WITH AllEvents AS (
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        ehubinput
),
EventB AS (
select
    EventB
From AllEvents
Where EventB Is Not NUll
),
EventC AS (
    select EventC
from AllEvents
Where EventC Is Not NUll
)

Select * From EventB 
 Inner Join EventC 
On DATEDIFF(day, EventB, EventC) BETWEEN 0 AND 5 
AND EventB.EventB.Claim.Uri = EventC.EventC.Claim.EventBUri
```

Unfortunately, my code will output EventB + x(for each EventC) * EventC instead of EventB + Last EventC....

Can anyone help me with this?

**Update:**

[This is my input](https://pastebin.com/evRqRhe8).

[This is my current output](https://pastebin.com/uprAw8TE). (I only want the latest EventC combined together with EventB, not every event in the stream as I do it right now)

Comment: So you want essentially just to take the last pair of (EventB,EventC) of what you already have? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @kgalic Yes. I wan't to output the related (pair) EventB each time an EventC is received. I updated my question with the current state of my query, the input I use and the output I currently get. I also added a bounty which I would love to give  away for the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your case, and came up with the following query:

```
WITH AllEvents AS (
  SELECT 
    *
  FROM
  Input
),
EventB AS (
 select
 EventB
 From AllEvents
 Where EventB Is Not NUll
),
EventC AS (
  select EventC, EventC.Time
  from AllEvents
  Where EventC Is Not NUll
),
test as (
  Select *, EventC.* From EventB 
  Inner Join EventC 
  On DATEDIFF(day, EventB, EventC) BETWEEN 0 AND 5 
 AND EventB.EventB.Claim.Uri = EventC.EventC.Claim.EventBUri)


select topone() over (order by Time) from test  GROUP BY TumblingWindow(second, 10)
```

For the series of the events, it will always return the last combination of (EventC, EventB) pair that matches. In case that this is not your expected output, could you please for the specified input above write the expected output?

I used VS2019 and Stream Analytics extension. I specified local inputs per your description above.

**Update**

The query has been updated. I noticed that only your last EventC in sample payload contains the property 'Time'. By having that property for each event C, and with the query above you would get 'Wasserburg' as a result.

Of course, output has to be formatted, but result in that case is correct.

**Further update**
I played a bit more with this as I found it really interesting and came up with the following query that is conceptually different from the previous one, and I would say even more precise:

```
-- timestamp by how events are enqueued
WITH AllEvents AS (
    SELECT 
       Input
     FROM 
     Input timestamp by input.EventEnqueuedUtcTime  
    ),

-- get the last eventB, because only last eventB is relevant
EventB AS (
    select last(AllEvents.Input) over (limit duration(minute, 1)  when AllEvents.input.EventB Is Not NUll)  as EventB 
    From AllEvents 
 ),
 LastB as (select topone() over (order by EventB.Time) from EventB GROUP BY  slidingwindow(second, 60)),

 -- get the last eventC
 EventC AS (
    select last(AllEvents.Input) over (limit duration(minute, 1)  when AllEvents.input.EventC Is Not NUll)  as EventC 
    From AllEvents 
 ),
LastC as (select topone() over (order by EventC.Time) from EventC GROUP BY  slidingwindow(second, 60)),

-- create the result if the join between last EventB and last EventC exists
ResultJoin as (
   Select LastB.topone.*, LastC.topone.* From LastB 
   Inner Join LastC 
   On DATEDIFF(second, LastB, LastC) BETWEEN 0 AND 60 
   AND LastB.topone.EventB.EventB.Claim.Uri  = LastC.topone.EventC.EventC.Claim.EventBUri)

-- get the last event that is a pair of EventB,EventC
select topone() over (order by EventB.Time) into Output from ResultJoin  GROUP BY  slidingwindow(second, 60)

-- Just a cross-check what is the last event B
select * into Output1 from LastB
```

I used time window functions because you mentioned that events are arriving in a minute time-frame. So essentially, the idea is to extract the last B event and lastC event, and then the matching one to propagate to the output.

I tested it on the real event hub with event hub message publisher so that I can simulate the event flow, similar like in your example:
[image]

And after that I watched the output locally to see if I would get the correct result after the last event:

[image]

Also, I added the time property to every event(B and C), as you can see it from the message simulator because that property is used to order the events in the query. Of course, you can replace that with some other property, like EventEnqueuedUtcTime or something similar.

I hope you would find one of these two different approaches useful for your final solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This looks very promising. The only issue I currently have, is that the outputed event contains the entity with city "Berlin", but I would expect the city to be "Wasserburg" since this was the last event.

Comment: I have updated the query and answer, please have a look at my comments

Comment: Thanks Kresimir, I will test that with real data that all have the time property on monday and will give you further feedback. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: Sure, please do so :) have a nice weekend!

Comment: Hi @MartinBrandl, any luck on this topic, or we should try to dig deeper :) ?

Comment: Sorry kgalic, I am on a sick leave and had no time to test it. I will accept your answer anyway since it seems to work on my local environment. 

However, can you please tell me what `GROUP BY TumblingWindow(second, 10)` does here? I expect arround 40 Events / sec and I need to process lets say all 35 that are from type EventB. 

Also, I expect to deal with another Event - EventD which will be related to EventB and EventC. I will need to consolidate this event similar as with EventB and process it to another function. Can I do this in the same Job? 
Thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: Hello @MartinBrandl. I added another solution, which I tested a bit deeper. Tumbling window in the first query I used just as an experiment to reduce the time frame because you mentioned earlier that B comes once per minute, and C a bit more frequently. In the latest update I am using the sliding windows which is one minute long and is more precise for your requirement. If you look in the documentation I think that SlidingWindow function fits more to your requirement than Tumbling one.

Comment: So idea is(in the latest update), to take the last B that arrived witin last minute, then the Event C and see if the last C matches with the last B.  If it does it will just print it to the output.

Comment: This solution also ignores B events older than a minute, because you just need the last one.. But in any case, have a look at both approaches and you will see which fits the solution better, or which one is closer to the final result.. 
P.S. I wish you a quick recovery :)

Comment: Sorry, I probably wasn't clear enough. One or many EventC are always related to a single EventB. The EventB is sent only once whereas multiple related EventC are sent over the next 5 days (so I won't find them in a 1-Minute timeframe). I need to combine each EventC with the related EventB and sent it to an Azure Function.

Comment: I see.. One of the queries above can be adjusted for that easy, most probably the first one. Just to make sure I understand every part of it, is it true that in any case, you take the last eventB, not all events B? Each next B overrides the previous one? Your last answer indicates that is not the case..

Comment: In any case, I will keep the 'further update' section, because this use case is slightly more complex in my opinion, so maybe would be helpful to someone..

Comment: There is only one eventB with Uri lets say B/123 and lets say 100 eventC that are linked to that eventB. Each time a eventC is sent, I have to combine that eventC with the related eventB and forward it to an azure function. This is one "case" example, but there are a few thousend of eventB comming / day and arround 100 eventC per eventB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201879/discussion-between-kgalic-and-martin-brandl).